# Why is my program only printing one grade?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Write a program to calculate students average test scores and their grades. You may
assume the following data:

```
Johnson 85 83 77 91 76
Aniston 80 90 95 93 48
Cooper 78 81 11 90 73
Gupta 92 83 30 69 87
Blair 23 45 96 38 59
Clark 60 85 45 39 67
Kennedy 77 31 52 74 83
Bronson 93 94 89 77 97
Sunny 79 85 28 93 82
Smith 85 72 49 75 63
```

Use three arrays: a one-dimensional array to store the student names, a (parallel) twodimensional
array to store the test score, and a parallel one-dimensional array to store
grades. Your program must contain at least the following methods: a method to read
and store data into two arrays, a method to calculate the average test score and grade.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment2Ques2 {
```

Comment: When your code prints out `Grades`, how are you expecting it to know how many grades to print out? Why do you think it will output five grades? Where do you think the code to put spaces between the grades is? Why does the last `for` loop have `i < Grades.length` as the loop condition?

Comment: Without i.Grades.length it wouldn’t print any grades unless I’m completely lost and confused .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate grades in AvgCal.  Your loop structure appears to be

```
for each of the 10 students
    for each of the 5 marks per student
       calculate the student's average
    end of average calculation
    set one grade for the student based on his average
end of student grade calculation
```

So you get one grade per student because that's all you calculate. And in fact that's all you can store in your program as written: you declare `char Grades[10]`, i.e., you have only one character to hod the grade for each student.

Your indentation is a bit funky so it's harder to see than it should be. Note the layout of my pseudocode; your Java should be similarly indented.

I think you've actually done what the assignment asked for - each student gets one grade based on their average score. Why do you think he/she should get 5 grades?

By the way, this statement

```
 System.out.println(Studt_Names[i] +":  " +Grades);
```

will print out some cybercrud like "[C@139a55" (identically) for each student, not the content of the Grades array and certainly not a single entry in the array. `Grades[i]` would make sense. Did you transcribe it correctly?

Comment: I think my code is actually correct and it is suppose to print one grade for the average of their marks. It's just that the lecturer did not ever clearly specify what he wants as the output because sometimes he likes to add his own thing into the question at the last minute. I will ask him for like the 5th time to specify what he needs and i'll let you know. If you and i are right then I'm so sorry for wasting your time i feel bad.

Comment: No apology required.